# Attached docker stack deploy

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-stack

The `docker-compose` utility is attached to the terminal by default allowing you to see that's happening with all of your containers which is very convenient for development. Does the `docker stack deploy` command support something like this when the activity of the running containers gets rendered in one terminal in real time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Docker [website](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stack_deploy/#extended-description) the only *log* displayed is:

```
docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml vossibility

Ignoring unsupported options: links

Creating network vossibility_vossibility
Creating network vossibility_default
Creating service vossibility_nsqd
Creating service vossibility_logstash
Creating service vossibility_elasticsearch
Creating service vossibility_kibana
Creating service vossibility_ghollector
Creating service vossibility_lookupd
```

However, there's a command which displays the logs:

```
docker service logs --follow
```

Therefore, on a Linux system you could combine both commands and you will get the desired output

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a merged output of the logs ("attached" for a stack deploy is a different thing with progress bars).

You can't get the logs for the full stack just yet ([see issue #31458 to track the progress of this request](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31458)), but you can get the logs for all of the containers in a service with `docker service logs`.